# Including complexType from XSD into OWL ontology

Tags: xsd, owl, protege

Good day,

I use Protege 5.5 to create my ontology of my software. I found that a creation of some user type duplicate ones in xsd file. So I want to include my **local** xsd file into my ontology.
I have [example](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-xsch-datatypes/) here (2.3) but could not understand how to use it.

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/refresh/ontologies/2020/9/MYONTOLOGY#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix ANPA: <http://www.semanticweb.org/refresh/ontologies/2020/9/ANPA#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix local: <file:/../xsd/local_file.xsd#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/refresh/ontologies/2020/9/MYONTOLOGY> .
```

Comment: how do you want to "include" the XSD? I mean, an XSD file is not an ontology, right? So, your task would be to convert the XSD to an ontology first. Your link shows some old discussion of a working group. I doubt this is part of OWL 2 standard. Honestly, wouldn't it be easier to just create whatever your XSD contains in OWL? What is in your XSD file? Where and how in your ontology do you want to use it?

Comment: Yep, maybe you are right. I thought someone somehow have had same problem. Xsd is not so gross and I just convert or reimplement one.

Comment: Well, I didn't say it doesn't make sense, I'm just saying its less error prone if you can do it manually - but, indeed there are approaches and tools, see for example http://www.incunabulum.de/projects/it/xsdimport/ and https://rhizomik.net/redefer/xsd2owl and https://search.proquest.com/openview/1897e267b6156bdcf46f6b0db7609c8f/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=1976346 and https://github.com/srdc/ontmalizer and ...